# O365 Group Site Creation (SharePoint Site)

Tags: azure, sharepoint, office365, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

By default, when creating an O365 Group, the SharePoint Site that provides document storage for the Group is not created automatically. It gets created on demand when a user navigates to the site for the first time.

I had a provisioning script that got around this problem by making a HTTP GET request to the URL that the user would normally navigate to from Outlook, which looked like: https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/groupstatus.aspx?id=[groupId]&target=documents

Something must have changed recently because this no longer triggers the Site creation, so my script times out.

Looking at the network traffic when I manually create a group and navigate to the site, I see some calls being made to https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/_api/GroupSiteManager/Create?groupId='[groupId]';

Is this "GroupSiteManager" endpoint documented anywhere, or is there an established (supported) method for forcing the Group Site to be created automatically?

I am using a Provider Hosted Add-In in conjunction with a middle tier processing API, both in Azure, Authenticated with Azure AD (WindowsAzureBearerAuthentication), and Application Permissions to Microsoft Graph.

Comment: Hello David, I've run into the same issue you were facing and I'm wondering if you got any helpful information?

Comment: Hi Andreas, unfortunately I have not been able to find any documentation for a supported solution.

Answer (score 1):

I created an O365 Group with MS Graph and got an `resource not found` error when i tried to retrieve information about the site right after that - a assume the same is happening for you.
However, when i tried again a few seconds later it came up with all the information i needed.
Maybe try a GET to this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<your group id>/drive/root/webUrl
```

at least for me it gave this information after the second try within a few seconds:

```
cache-control: private
content-type: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8
request-id: <some id>
client-request-id: <some id>
Status Code: 200
{
    "@odata.context": https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups(<your group id>)/drive/root/webUrl",
    "value": "https://<your tennant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<generated SharePoint name>/Shared%20Documents"
}
```